# MongoDB "select into"

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about an mongodb query.

my dataset (more than 20 000 000 documents)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c0386945544b2679dbdded"),
        "local" : "XXXX",
        "mail" : "email@email.com",
}
```

I want to find email who are in different local.
Example
    
    `local,email
    A, a@a.com
    B, b@b.com
    C, c@c.com
    D, a@a.com`

Result must be :
   
    `a@a.com = 2
    b@b.com = 1
    c@c.com = 1`

And the best is something like that :
   
    `a@a.com,2,(A,D)
    b@b.com,1,(B)
    c@c.com,1,(C)`

thanks for your help

Comment: Please share your code, and where that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  aggregate command,

```
db.document.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                mail: "$mail",
                local: "$local"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.mail",
            local: {
                $addToSet: "$_id.local"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }])
```